# Can FileSavePicker be used in UWP background process?

Tags: c#, uwp, background

In my UWP, I implemented a Toast Notification that is triggered in background process.  When user interact with the toast, another background task with ToastNotificationActionTrigger is activated.  In that ToastNotificationActionTrigger activated background task, I want to show the FileSavePicker letting user pick folder/file.  But the call to show the FileSavePicker dialog threw "Invalid window handle" exception.

Can FileSavePicker be used in UWP background process?

Answer (score 0):

> But the call to show the FileSavePicker dialog threw "Invalid window handle" exception.

I'm afraid you can't show  `FileSavePicker` dialog in background, Because, the  `FileSavePicker` dialog can't be invoked in non-UI thread. For your scenario, we suggest you launch the app first then call [`FileSavePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-19041) in the uithread.